# Idiom for a person who gets owned/caught red handed for his mistake but shows as if nothing is wrong

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

What is the idiom/expression for a person who gets owned/caught red-handed for his logical fallacy/mistake/theft and knows he is wrong but has the tenacity to show as if nothing is wrong?

In fact, he ridicules the corrector as if he were absurd to accuse an infallible person.

Comment: "He passes it off", means that a person who is found to have done something wrong/embarrassing/criminal is able easily to dismiss it "without turning a hair".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may use the idiomatic expression ***[have the gall to do something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-the-gall-to-do-something)***:

> - to do something rude and unreasonable that most people would be too embarrassed to do.

(MacMillan Dictionary)

- have the gall to pretend they did nothing wrong and to ridicule the corrector.

Comment: For bonus idiomaticity points, render it as *sheer, brazen gall* :o)

Answer (score 0):

As an adjective, *shameless* has just this meaning. If a noun is required, then the (somewhat rare) *brazenface* would cover it, although this also might refer to someone who tells an unwelcome truth without fearing the consequences.